# clientWidth value not correct of clipped div with dynamic width (using useLayoutEffect and SSR)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, server-side-rendering

I have a div (`.inner`) with dynamic width based on its content.

```
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

This is clipped by its parent (`.clipper`) using `overflow: hidden`:

```
.clipper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

I want the full non clipped width of the inner element, I do this like so:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const { clientWidth: innerWidth } = innerRef.current;
  // work with innerWidth..

  }, []);
```

However, it's `innerWidth`, `clientWidth` or bounding box width all return the clipped value (370 in this case).
[image: The clipped value]

Inspecting it in the DOM shows it real width (723).
[image: The desired value]

Also, after a Hot Module Reload the console logs the desired width once..

Can anybody enlighten me whats going on? Does it have something to do with a re-render, or something with console.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

It turns out that my wrong clientWidth value is due to a mismatch between the initial, non-hydrated UI and the intended UI.

I thought this would be fixable by lazily loading my component until after the client side JS loads and hydrates the component, see option 2 [here](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/e7d97cdf38a2907924ea12e4ebdf3c85):

This didn't work however, so I introduced a little hack using `setTimeout`, and using `useIsomorphicLayoutEffect` to surpress a useLayoutEffect SSR warning (see [here](https://medium.com/@alexandereardon/uselayouteffect-and-ssr-192986cdcf7a)).

After the timeout I receive the correct DOM value.

```
useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
  // Check for refs
  if (containerRef.current && innerRef.current) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const { clientWidth: containerWidth } = containerRef.current;
      const { clientWidth: innerWidth } = innerRef.current;

      maxTransform.current = innerWidth - containerWidth;

      checkForBoundaries();
    }, 1000);
  }
}, [checkForBoundaries]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**What's the size of the displayed content**

If you need to know how much space the actual displayed content takes up, including padding but not including the border, margins, or scrollbars, you want to use the `Element.clientWidth` and `Element.clientHeight` properties

**How big is the content**

If you need to know the actual size of the content, regardless of how much of it is currently visible, you need to use the `Element.scrollWidth` and `Element.scrollHeight`

[see the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements) for more details

Comment: It's obvious that you didn't read my question very well, I'm very aware of these properties, but they give me a different value then desired

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn can you please explain me that how it's giving you the wrong value ? you are using `clientWidth` it will give you the visible part which is 370 px if you will use `scrollWidth` it will give you 723

Comment: you question says `I want the full non clipped width of the inner element` to get that you will have to use `scrollWidth`

Comment: My apologies, if you read it that way, it reads out like that is my question. However, `can you please explain me that how it's giving you the wrong value` < this is my question. Using `scrollWidth`, `clientWidth` or any other property all give me the wrong value. I'm thinking it's more React related.

Comment: `can you please explain me that how it's giving you the wrong value` well what i meant by that is what are the value difference ( what are you expecting and what it's giving you ) because I was guessing that it's because of your style is being applied after you calculate the `clientWidth` ( it's so obvious ) also in you question you say `clientWidth or bounding box width all return the clipped value (370 in this case)` and this is the correct behavior that's why I was asking you what value you expect

Comment: Value difference is quite litteraly described in my question (expected value vs received), and it's not quite expected behaviour as it previously worked. If you could edit your answer I'll remove your downvote.

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn I am confused at this point because in your question you say `However, it's innerWidth, clientWidth or bounding box width all return the clipped value (370 in this case)` and the documentation on MDN says `how much space the actual **displayed** content takes = clientWidth` so how it's wrong

 displayed content = 370 and value you are getting = 370

Comment: however when the first time on HRM you get 723 because I am assuming your style it not applied yet because when you are using HRM your style are inside JavaScript so first you compute clientWidth then your style gets applied now the displayed part is 370 so you get 370 after that

Comment: I understand, however `scrollWidth` gave me the same value, so I still had to deal with the problem described in my answer.

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn you don't need to introduce any hanky way like setTimeout just make sure your style get loaded first or if you can't do that you can compare `clientWidth` and `scrollWidth` to check if style is applied or not but how does that make my answer deserve -ve vote ?

Comment: style is a render blocking asset so in any way it should be loaded before your JavaScript code is running

Comment: `If you could edit your answer I'll remove your downvote.` I still don't understand what i need to edit ?

Comment: Yes but clientWidth and scrollWidth have exactly the same value, it's because of a UI mismatch described in my answer. It's a known SSR issue with useLayoutEffect. My issue is already resolved, could you please calm down?. As for the downvote, I acted too fast but I can't remove your downvote unless you edit your question, so if you just edit a tiny thing I can remove it.

Comment: I have edited the answer but please can you give me some links where I can learn about this issue because I still don't understand the issue very well and because of that I can't sleep at night :p and setTimeout is not a satisfactory answer for me Yet

Comment: You have even received my bounty ;). No setTimeout is indeed a hack.. Not really satisfied either but it does solve my issue. I have links about the issue in my answer. The first one describes the issue a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty ( I don't deserve it ) but will try to dig into the issue and update if I find something satisfactory.